# jinja2 failed to work with the pages collected by flask-flatpages

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-flatpages

In my code, FlatPages collects and renders all of my .html files inside of /pages/ folder.

```
pages = FlatPages(app)
@app.route('/<path:path>/')
# path is filename without extension '.html'
def page(path):
    page = pages.get_or_404(path)
    # print(f'page path is {page.path}')
    return render_template('page.html', page=page)

@freezer.register_generator
def pagelist():
    for page in pages:
        yield url_for('page', path=page.path)
```

Now suppose I have abc.html inside of /pages/ folder and whatever Jinja2 expressions I typed in, the app won't recognize it. For example, if I typed in {{ 1 + 1}}, if Jinja2 were recognized, it should show 2; but my app just showed {{ 1 + 1}} on the web browser.

Is that because of the address format '/path:path/'?
How could I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I probably found out the reason why it doesn't work that way.

The to-be published files (TBP) in pages/ folder are rendered through render_template('page.html', page=page) inside flask app .py file.

page.html is a template in templates/ folder and it works for all of TBPs. Notice that page.html and TBPs are located in different folders, but they have a close relationship, like template and content. So the content of each TBP is pulled out and inserted into page.html, usually between {% block content %} and {% endblock %}, and specifically, {{ page.html | safe}} section. Other page.meta data could be somewhere around {{ page.html |safe }} section.

So any Jinja expression inside of TBPs would not be recognized due to the {{ page.html | safe}} regulation. They will just be literally shown as they are.